# QMenu: Set text color for specific QAction

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a `QMenu` as context menu that looks like this:

```
Menu
- information_A
- information_B
- information_C
```

Now i want the entry `information_B` to be painted in a different color. How can i archive this?

Comment: It is always hard to say that something is not possible, but... I'd say impossible. At least in an easy way. I might overlook somethig, but I am afraid, you have to subclass QMenu and do the drawing yourself, i.e. overloading QPaintEvent.

Comment: ive checked the source of `QMenu`s paint event and it calls all sorts of hidden members. so i guess when using the `LGPL` there is no way to use existing functionality?

Comment: I don't know. I checked the available api and did not find something, which could solve your problem easily. As I said, you probably have to subclass QMenu yourself and overload QPaintEvent. This has nothing to do with LGPL. I just don't think this easy looking QMenu might be surprisingly difficult to be drawn. I suppose... <-- you see much speculaton ...you have to find the proper rectangle for you menu item and draw it with help of the active style yourself. Nowadays I would not bother with something like that (if the choice is mine), but use qml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I found the best solution in this post:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626601/qt-set-stylesheet-for-a-qmenu-object) 
In your case it would be as simple as:

```
QMenu contextMenu(this);
QString menuStyle(
        "QMenu::item{"      
        "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"
        "}"
    );
contextMenu.setStyleSheet(menuStyle);
```

For more options and possibilities take a look at the answer in the link I provided above.

PREVIOUS SOLUTION: 
You can use `QWidgetAction` instead of `QAction`, and define your `QLabel` with text and stylesheet you want, and then assign it to your `QWidgetAction`. But keep in mind that you have to tweak the *width* and *height* of your `QLabel`, in order for it to look the same as `QAction` does.

**Sample code:**

```
// label
QLabel *text = new QLabel(QString("your text here"), this);
text->setStyleSheet("color: blue"); 
// init widget action
QWidgetAction *widAct= new QWidgetAction(this);
widAct->setDefaultWidget(text);
contextMenu.addAction(widAct);
```

Comment: a little late but i like it :)

Comment: Better late then never :)

Comment: QWigetAction type actions don't trigger signal and don't call slot.

Comment: The updated solution changes colors for all items while the OP asked about a solution to set color of just one item.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to style a single item in the menu, you can set it as default with `QMenu::setDefaultAction` and style a default menu item with the `QMenu::item:default` selector.

I.e.:

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu("My menu");
QAction* actionToStyle = new QAction("My action");
menu->addAction(actionToStyle);
menu->setDefaultAction(actionToStyle);
menu->setStyleSheet("QMenu::item:default { color: #ff0000; }");
```

The limitation of this method is that it can apply special styling to only one item.