# QT: set stylesheet for a QMenu object

Tags: qt

What's the correct way to apply styles for a QMenu object?

I'm trying this:

```
QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);
contextMenu.addAction(new QAction(tr("Hello"), this));
contextMenu.setStyleSheet("*:hover { color:#FFF; } *:!hover { color:#aaa; }");
```

I'm trying to set different text colors for when the mouse is over the menu option and when the mouse isn't over the option. But it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In case of `QMenu` styling use `QMenu::item:selected`
2. Here is an example

   ```
    QMenu::item{
    background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    QMenu::item:selected{
    background-color: rgb(0, 85, 127);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
   ```
3. In your case

   ```
     QString  menuStyle(
              "QMenu::item{"
              "background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);"
              "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
              "}"
              "QMenu::item:selected{"
              "background-color: rgb(0, 85, 127);"
              "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
              "}"
           );

     this->setStyleSheet(menuStyle);
   ```
4. Refer the [Qt Style Sheets example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu) for more options